# Insert Text to Activecell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do i insert a text named "Total" to a selected cell using VBA

I used

```
Activecell.Name="Total"
Selection.Name="Total"
```

But both of them is not working, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you are looking for is any of the following:

`ActiveCell.Value = "Total"
 ActiveCell.Value2 = "Total"`

Comment: Awesome! For larger datasets, Value2 is faster.

Also, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: I am curious if you actually tested `ActiveCell.Text = "Total"`? Because if you did, you would see right away that it fails because the `Text` property is read-only.

Comment: You are right in both that `.text` is read only and that I in fact did not test this (I am at work :(  )

Comment: Yes `ActiveCell.Text = "Total"` didn't work but thankfully`ActiveCell.Value = "Total"`worked fine. Thanks again for prompt response:)